# How to pass a string from a make file into a c++ program

Tags: c++, c, makefile

It seems on a program I've inherited we can pass in make variables that are numbers but I'd like to pass in a string now. When they are passed in as numbers it is as the following:

```
CFLAGS += -DBUILD_NUMBER=$(BUILD_NUMBER)
```

and i can access it as an int like so:

```
fprintf(stderr, "\n%s v%d.%d.%d.%d\n", APPNAME, MAJOR_VERSION, MINOR_VERSION, PATCH_VERSION, BUILD_NUMBER, MYBRANCH);
```

but I do not seem to be achieving the same with a string.

```
CFLAGS += -DMYBRANCH=$(BRANCH)

fprintf(stderr, "\n%s v%d.%d.%d.%d.%s\n", APPNAME, MAJOR_VERSION, MINOR_VERSION, PATCH_VERSION, BUILD_NUMBER, MYBRANCH);
```

I get this error with the above:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int args_parse_cmd_line(int, char**)’:
<command-line>:0:10: error: ‘FIL’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:72:114: note: in expansion of macro ‘MYBRANCH’
 %s\n", APPNAME, MAJOR_VERSION, MINOR_VERSION, PATCH_VERSION, BUILD_NUMBER, MYBRANCH);
                                                                            ^~~~~~~~
```

Can someone give me a tip on what I'm doing wrong? "FIL-1234" is the example of our branch name that I'm trying to add to our build meta data for tractability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This preprocessor trick should work

```
#define xstr(s) str(s)
#define str(s) #s

fprintf(stderr, "\n%s v%d.%d.%d.%d.%s\n", APPNAME, MAJOR_VERSION, MINOR_VERSION, PATCH_VERSION, BUILD_NUMBER, xstr(MYBRANCH));
```

It's clear from your error that `MYBRANCH` is being expanded into `FIL-1234` when, not unreasonably, the compiler looks for a variable `FIL`. You need to turn the macro expansion into a string literal and the code above should do that. Although I haven't tested anything.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is ideal but it works.

```
CFLAGS += -DMYBRANCH=\"$(BRANCH)\"
```

I think John's solution is attractive as I'm not crazy about escaping characters.